# editText get text kotlin

Tags: android-edittext, kotlin

How to get editText in kotlin and display with toast.

```
var editTextHello = findViewById(R.id.editTextHello)
```

I tried this but shows object

```
Toast.makeText(this,editTextHello.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're missing a cast of the `View` you get from `findViewById` to `EditText`:

```
var editTextHello = findViewById(R.id.editTextHello) as EditText
```

Then, you want to display the `text` property of the `EditText` in your toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

---

For the record, this is just the more idiomatic Kotlin equivalent to calling `getText()` on your `EditText`, like you'd do it in Java:

```
Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: I tried that but I get error unresolved reference text

Comment: Right, a type cast was also missing, I've edited my answer.

Comment: editTextHello.text should give you an editable object, using toString() will give you string.

Comment: Can you please explain why and when do we need type casting? For the part 'as EditText'

Answer (score 32):

This is Kotlin, not java. You do not need to get the id of it. In kotlin, just write:

```
var editTextHello = editTextHello.text.toString()
```

use the beauty of kotlin ;-)

P.s: BTW, better to choose xml IDs like edx_hello and for the kotlin part, var editTextHello. Then you can differentiate between xml vars and kotlin vars.

Comment: without gettin ID how to get the value entered in Edittext?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown you need to configure the [Kotlin Android Extensions plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding) in order to use this.

Answer (score 4):

The voted answer is correct but it is not the best one for the Kotlin's world. If you're really interested in entering into this world, I'd recommend you to use extensions. From Kotlin you have `kotlin-android-extensions` and with it you can do this:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.reference_to_your_view.editTextHello`

and this:

`Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

please, forget about the getText()... use just this, it is more clean.

ps: read about extensions and you will see you can create your own extensions and do an even more clean usage of the Toast. Something like this:

```
fun Context.showToast(text: CharSequence, duration: Int = Toast.LENGTH_LONG) = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration).show()
```

and it being used like this through your classes:

`showToast("uhuuu")`

but this is beyond the scope we're talking about here.

from: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead, it's working fine

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
Toast.makeText(this, editText.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `editTextHello.text`

```
  Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello.text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

If you make `edittext` as nullable then the line would be

```
Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello?.text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin calling **.text** on your EditText is fine no need to do *getText* or *toString*

```
Toast.makeText(this, editTextHello.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

with button click

```
button?.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,editText.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Even don't need findViewById

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a cast of the View you get from findViewById to EditText.
But you need a "if" if the control exist then get the text:

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.editText_main) as EditText
if (editText != null) {
   val showString = editText.text.toString()
   Toast.makeText(this, showString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `as EditText` like suggest from Top Answer.
Pls follow these steps:

1/ Define the EditText var global:

```
private lateinit var couponCode: EditText
```

2/ Attach ID for it in onCreate overrided:

```
couponCode = findViewById(R.id.couponCode)
```

3/ Now, can use it anywhere in class to get the Text that you need like this:

```
val text = couponCode.text.toString() // if don't use .toString(), the func couponCode will return an Editable type, not String type that you want
```