# Why is Android Studio opening looper.java when I try to debug?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been trying to make a simple app in Kotlin using Android Studio, and it looks like there's something wrong with my code. Every time it gets to

```
var add1 = middle1.toInt()
```

of the code, the app either crashes or the debugger opens looper.java. I am very new to app development, and I have only ever used Python before this week, so thank you for understanding.

Code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val getSum = findViewById(R.id.GetSum) as Button
        getSum.setOnClickListener {
            var addend1 = findViewById(R.id.Addend1) as EditText
            var addend2 = findViewById(R.id.Addend2) as EditText
            var middle1 = addend1.toString()
            var middle2 = addend2.toString()
            var add1 = middle1.toInt()
            var add2 = middle2.toInt()
            var sum = findViewById(R.id.Sum) as TextView
            var result = (add1 + add2).toString()
            sum.setText(result)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `EditText.toString()` is not the right way to get text from EditText. Use `EditText.getText().toString()` (Java) to get text. Kotlin should be something like `EditText.text.toString()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267572/edittext-get-text-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code. Try this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val getSum = findViewById(R.id.GetSum) as Button
    val addend1 = findViewById(R.id.Addend1) as EditText
    val addend2 = findViewById(R.id.Addend2) as EditText
    var sum = findViewById(R.id.Sum) as TextView

    getSum.setOnClickListener {

        var add1 = addend1.text.toString().toInt()
        var add2 = addend2.text.toString().toInt()

        var result = (add1 + add2).toString()
        sum.setText(result)

    }
}
```

}